# A&A 1942 2nd ed: Is it necessary to build an industrial complex in order to mobilize units?

Tags: axis-and-allies

If Russia doesn't build an industrial complex, can units be mobilized in any controlled territory?

I don't see any complexes printed on the board itself to start the game off, does that mean I have to buy one in order to mobilize units?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every country needs to have an industrial complex to build units. But every country starts out with at least one (America, Germany and Russia have two). So you don't need to build another one unless you have lost one.

If you are Japan or England and you've lost your industrial complex (around your capital city), you're out of the game anyway (unless an ally recaptures your capital). If you're Russia, you can afford to lose Karelia, but not Moscow, if Germany, you can afford to lose Rome but not Berlin, and if America, you can afford to lose Los Angeles (the Western U.S.) but not Washington D.C.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the setup charts for each country, some territories have "Industrial Complex" listed of one of the units to be placed.  I suspect that they were not printed directly on the board because they could then get covered up by other pieces.

You can find a copy of the setup charts at 
http://www.axisandallies.org/resources-downloads/setup-chart-axis-allies-1942-second-edition/